# SQL close close Gaps in data over time

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, gaps-and-islands

I have a table of play data that I'm using for a prototype.  I'm generating the data while I'm at work, but when I leave and my machine goes to sleep, the data generation stops.  This has cause large gaps in my collection of items.

I would like to be able to shift the values of each item in the `DateTimeCreated` collumn of my table so that there isn't a gap of more than 10 minutes between any item and the next generated item.

The structure of the table is like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Items](
    [Id] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [DateTimeCreated] [datetimeoffset](7) NOT NULL,
    [AuthorId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [Source] [varchar](max) NOT NULL,       
    [FullText] [varchar](max) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Items] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
```

I was thinking about doing this in L2S, but I have over 1 million records, so IDK if that is the best solution (iterating over each item).  I know there has to be some way to do this in SQL that will be much faster.

Comment: Classic Gaps-And-Islands problem. Don't tell the guy to use cursors, Not needed.

Comment: Cursors = Satan. If, no one beats me to it, I'll post a non-cursor solution tonight

Comment: @Dems - I only have 10-15 gaps of ~12 hours in each gap.  I'd like to maintain the "randomness" of the currently generated data's datetime. I'm pulling data from organic sources (random tweets, facebook posts, etc) so I'd like to keep as much of the organicness as possible. But, in the end, I'm open to anything :)

Comment: @joe - Are all of your existing ID's sequential? Or do they have gaps due to deletes or failed inserts?

Comment: @Dems, yes you are correct, a cursors solution would probably be quicker and more intuitive to write than a set based solution... I was getting a little carried away.

Comment: You've tagged this Denali. So that means that the extended `OVER` clause is available to you with `lag` etc.? Also if you are just fiddling the `DateTimeCreated` column why not fiddle it entirely and just change all records to have a 10 minute gap? Not really sure what you are doing here?

Comment: @Dems - the ID's are GUIDs; MartinSmith - Yes, I'm using Denali. The reason I can't do 10 min gaps between items is because there are ~20-40 items per minute in the DB.  I'm showing some "Items Over Time" type graphs based on content, so they need to look convincingly organic.

Comment: You should be able to adapt the basic idea from [this excellent post by meouw](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8145112/533120).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative Ranking-Functions Approach (not 100% tested):

```
DECLARE @tenMinutes AS INT = 600;


WITH StartingPoints AS
(
    SELECT DateTimeCreated, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY DateTimeCreated) AS rownum
    FROM dbo.Items AS A
    WHERE NOT EXISTS(
        SELECT * FROM dbo.Items AS B
        WHERE B.DateTimeCreated < A.DateTimeCreated 
          AND DATEDIFF(SECOND,B.DateTimeCreated, A.DateTimeCreated) BETWEEN 0 AND @tenMinutes
    )
),
EndingPoints AS
(
    SELECT DateTimeCreated, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY DateTimeCreated) AS rownum
    FROM dbo.Items AS A
    WHERE NOT EXISTS(
        SELECT * FROM dbo.Items AS B
        WHERE A.DateTimeCreated < B.DateTimeCreated 
          AND DATEDIFF(SECOND,A.DateTimeCreated, B.DateTimeCreated) BETWEEN 0 AND @tenMinutes
    )
),
Islands AS
(
    SELECT S.DateTimeCreated AS start_range,
           E.DateTimeCreated AS end_range,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY S.DateTimeCreated) AS row_num
    FROM StartingPoints AS S
    JOIN EndingPoints AS E on E.rownum = S.rownum
),
Ofs AS
(
    SELECT I2.start_range, 
           I2.end_range,  
           I1.end_range AS prev,
           DATEDIFF(SECOND, I1.end_range, I2.start_range) AS offset 
    FROM Islands AS I1
    JOIN Islands AS I2 ON I2.row_num = I1.row_num + 1 OR I2.row_num IS NULL
),
CmlOfs AS
(
    SELECT O1.start_range,
           O1.end_range,
           O1.prev,
           O1.offset,
           (SELECT SUM(O2.offset) FROM Ofs AS O2
            WHERE O2.start_range <= O1.start_range) AS cum_offset
    FROM Ofs AS O1
),
UpdateQ AS
(
    SELECT Items.*, DATEADD(SECOND, -1 * CmlOfs.cum_offset, Items.DateTimeCreated) AS new_value
    FROM Items
    JOIN CmlOfs ON Items.DateTimeCreated BETWEEN CmlOfs.start_range AND CmlOfs.end_range
)
UPDATE UpdateQ
SET DateTimeCreated = new_value;
```

Comment: Wow, that's really tricky!  Your solution is very well organized and easy to follow!  I'm trying it out right now and I'll let you know how it goes!

Comment: @joe_coolish I must credit author Itzik Ben-Gan. If you want to learn some tricky sql, check him out

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to have an index on `DateTimeCreated` if you want this to be anything other than a pig.

It also assumes (as you said in your comment) there are few gaps compared to total number of records.

```
WITH
  gap (Start,Finish)
AS
(
  SELECT
    DateTimeCreated,
    (SELECT MIN(DateTimeCreated) FROM items AS lookup WHERE DateTimeCreated > DateTimeCreated)
  FROM
    items
  WHERE
    DATEADD(second, 600, DateTimeCreated) < (SELECT MIN(DateTimeCreated) FROM items AS lookup WHERE DateTimeCreated > DateTimeCreated)

  UNION ALL

  SELECT
    MAX(DateTimeCreated),
    MAX(DateTimeCreated)
  FROM
    items
)
,
  offset (Start,Finish,Offset)
AS
(
  SELECT
    [current].Start,
    (SELECT MIN(Start) FROM gap WHERE Start > [current].Start),
    DATEDIFF(second, Start, Finish) - 600
  FROM
    gap      AS [current]
)
,
  cumulative_offset (Start,Finish,Offset)
AS
(
  SELECT
    [current].Start,
    [current].Finish,
    SUM([cumulative].Offset)
  FROM
    offset    AS [current]
  INNER JOIN
    offset    AS [cumulative]
      ON [cumulative].Start <= [current].Start
)

UPDATE
  items
FROM
  cumulative_offset
SET
  DateTimeCreated = DATEADD(second, -Offset, DateTimeCreated)
INNER JOIN
  items
    ON  items.DateTimeCreated >  cumulative.Start
    AND items.DateTimeCreated <= cumulative.Finish
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your SQL.  I'm analyzing it right now.  I had no idea where to even start and this has taught me a lot already!